# How do you migrate from dmraid to mdadm on a working 14.04?

Tags: mdadm

I installed 14.04 LTS the other day on two Samsung 840 Pro's in RAID0 on my Intel FakeRAID BIOS setup (NO efi). It is running great, however during the initial boot the system seemed to have a broken Grub, so I used Boot-Repair from a live usb to fix it and apparently that converts mdadm back to dmraid. So, now here I am running in a really nice fast raid setup but with a deprecated mdraid. I wanted mdadm since it appears to be actively updated.

How do you go back to mdadm on a working system without damaging your system? Is this even possible?

Thank You!

Regards,
Rod

Comment: I'm not following: is fakeraid activated in the BIOS or not? If it is, deactivate it: Linux does a far better job.